# How to make responsive the listview of asp.net

Tags: listview, responsive-design, asp.net-4.5

I have a listview in asp.net 4.5 page. I'm populating the images in it. its working fine. but when i change the resolution of the browser other elements of the page are adjusting by the resolution but the images in the listview are not adjusting. Kindly tell me how do i do this? The code looks like this.

```
    <asp:ListView ID="lVGallery" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="galerySqlDataSource" GroupItemCount="2" OnItemCommand="lVGallery_ItemCommand">


            <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse;
            border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    No data was returned.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <EmptyItemTemplate>
        <td id="Td1" runat="server" />
    </EmptyItemTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
            <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="background-color: #E0FFFF; color: #333333;">
            <div>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ID=" + Eval("ID")%>'
                Height="100px" Width="100px"  />
                </div>
       </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="Table2" runat="server">
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                <td id="Td3" runat="server">
                    <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;
                        border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;
                        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/798213/problem-with-responsive-with-asp-net-datalist-cont
The LayoutTemplate contains a block level element (the div). This means that the ItemTemplate will be wrapped in the div which will take up the full available width.

You should be able to just remove div from the LayoutTemplate, make it a span, or make it a table like in the Selected Answer of the post I linked from @mshsayem

Comment: Please add essential parts of your link as part of your answer.